# Extending both T and SomeInterface<T> in Java

Tags: java, generics, multiple-inheritance, extends

I want to create a class that takes two parameters.  One should be typed simply as T.  The other should be typed as something that extends both T and `SomeInterface<T>`.  When I attempt this with

```
public class SomeClass<T, S extends SomeInterface<T> & T>
```

then Java complains with

"The type T is not an interface; it cannot be specified as a bounded parameter"

and if instead I attempt to create an interface for S with

```
public interface TandSomeInterface<T> extends SomeInterface<T>, T
```

then Java complains with

"Cannot refer to the type parameter T as a supertype"

Is there any way to do this in Java?  I think you can do it in C++...?

Comment: Note that C++ templates are a lot more powerful than Java generics. Just because it can be done in C++, doesn't mean it can be done in Java.

Comment: related: http://stackoverflow.com/a/13261667/697449

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can't create an interface that extends the type parameter `T` since there's no contract that would guarantee `T` to be an interface. And of course interface extending a class is not allowed.

Comment: But is there any way to circumvent this to get the same effect?

Answer (score 3):

this works if you extend an interface as well:

```
public class SomeClass<T extends I, S extends SomeInterface<T> & I>
```

but maybe it's not exactly what you want ...