# Generics Puzzler

Tags: java, generics, nested-generics

I am trying to figure out how to get generics to jump through hoops.

I have:

```
interface Root { }
interface Middle extends Root { }
class Type implements Root { }
```

And many "Subtype" classes:

```
class Subtype1 extends Type implements Middle { }
class Subtype2 extends Type implements Middle { }
...
```

What I want is to declare a class with two type parameters `T` and `S`, where `T` is bound by `Type` and `S` is bound by `T` and `Middle`.

I can't see a way with generics to ensure that `S` extends `T` AND implements `Middle`.
What I want is something like:

```
class Handler<T extends Root, S extends T, S extends Middle>;
```

or

```
class Handler<T extends Root, S extends <T extends Middle>>;
```

But of course neither are legal. Maybe there is some magic I am missing?

Comment: You cannot do this. You can have multiple bounds but they must be 0-1 Class plus multiple interfaces. You cannot have a Generic type in a multiple bound situation. I suspect this restriction was kept because to allow type in multiple bounds would create a lot of complexity to the syntax checker, for what is a rare edge case.

Comment: related: http://stackoverflow.com/a/13261667/697449

Comment: Thanks. That was my read as well but figured it was possible I was missing something in the spec. Casts it is!

Comment: Can you explain why declaring `Handler<T extends Root, S extends Subtype>` isn't enough? The only difference is that `T` could possibly be a more specific type than `S`, that's it.

Comment: `Handler<T extends Root, S extends Subtype>` means that Handler is bound to a single Subtype. I have several which means that Handler is no longer generic across Subtypes. In reality my code has half a dozen Subtypes which would mean an equal number of Handlers bound to the specific Subtype.

Comment: I made some edits to try and clarify your problem - could you please review my changes and let me know if anything is off?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try introducing an abstract class that extends `SubType` and implements `Middle`, so its type can be used in `Handler`.

```
abstract class MiddleSubtype extends Subtype implements Middle { }
```

Then,

```
class Handler<T extends Root, S extends MiddleSubtype> {  //...
```

**EDIT:** Following the update to the question, the same idea would look like:

```
abstract class MiddleType extends Type implements Middle { }

class Subtype1 extends MiddleType { }
class Subtype2 extends MiddleType { }
...

class Handler<T extends Root, S extends MiddleType> {  //...
```

Comment: Note that this is different from `T extends Root, S extends T ...` though, since `S` is no longer bound by `T`.

Comment: Yes and it ties Handler to one subtype. I actually have a bunch of subtypes which would mean a bunch of Handlers as well which is exactly  what I was trying to avoid.

Comment: @NickPalmer See my edit to this answer - I think this is close to what rgettman was suggesting.

Comment: This does in fact work for the revised question posed and so I am accepting it. Unfortunately my real type hierarchy is even MORE complicated and so I am stuck with casting. Call it a case of over simplifying for the question and the restrictions on Generics being problematic.

Comment: @NickPalmer If you have time to put together a follow-up question, I'm sure people would be interested.

Answer (score 0):

Or you could make S generic itself:

```
interface SInt<A,B> {}
class Handler<T extends Root, S extends SInt<T, Middle>>{}
```