# Can you specify a generic type that subclasses another generic type _and_ a concrete interface?

Tags: java, generics

I have a family of domain models, each of which has a subclass that extends it *and* implements a specific interface, like this (`Cloneable` is not the interface in question, it's for example purposes only):

```
class A{}
class B extends A implements Cloneable{}

class C{}
class D extends C implements Cloneable{}
```

I want to create a generic type signature that will enforce this pairing, I've tried this which **FAILS**:

```
<T1,T2 extends T1 & Cloneable> void f ( T1 t1, T2 t2 ){}
```

but I get message in my IntelliJ IDE `"Type parameter cannot be followed by other bounds"`; it still **FAILS** if I switch the order around to:

```
<T1,T2 extends Cloneable & T1> void f ( T1 t1, T2 t2 ){}
```

I get the message `"Interface expected here."`

Confusingly, both of these signatures **WORK**:

```
<T extends A & Cloneable> void f( A a, T t ){}
<T1,T2 extends T1> void f ( T1 t1, T2 t2 ){}
```

Is this just a weird limitation of Java's generic type system that I cannot have a generic class (ie `T2`) extend both *another* generic class (ie `T1`) *and* a concrete interface (eg `Cloneable`)?

**tl;dr:** So, why won't `<T1,T2 extends Cloneable & T1> void f ( T1 t1, T2 t2 ){}` compile: is it a limitation of the Java generic syntax or am I using the wrong syntax?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Java generics - Make Generic to extends 2 interfaces](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13101991/java-generics-make-generic-to-extends-2-interfaces) and [Why can't I use a type argument in a type parameter with multiple bounds?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/197190/why-cant-i-use-a-type-argument-in-a-type-parameter-with-multiple-bounds)

Comment: Yes, another weird and unfortunate limitation of Java typing that you can't do intersection type constraints if a type variable is involved.  The reason given is apparently to avoid "certain problematic cases".

Comment: @PaulBellora While the answer may be the same, my question is different from the one of two interfaces.

Comment: @JudgeMental It seems compile time checkable so I really would be curious to the actual specifics involved.

Comment: @ArtB See the edit to that question (which had a bounty) and my answer. It's a little confusing I know. The second linked post is more obviously a duplicate.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The answer is in [JLS 4.4](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se7/html/jls-4.html#jls-4.4):

```
TypeParameter:
    TypeVariable TypeBoundopt

TypeBound:
    extends TypeVariable
    extends ClassOrInterfaceType AdditionalBoundListopt

AdditionalBoundList:
    AdditionalBound AdditionalBoundList
    AdditionalBound

AdditionalBound:
    & InterfaceType
```

The `& Cloneable` is an AdditionalBound, which can only be used in an AdditionalBoundList. An AdditionalBoundList can only be used after ClassOrInterfaceType. And `T1` is a TypeVariable, not a ClassOrInterfaceType.

So, yes, it's a limitation of the Java generic syntax.

Answer (score 0):

> `<T1,T2 extends Cloneable & T1> void f ( T1 t1, T2 t2 ){}`
>
> I get the message "Interface expected here."

From the [**jls 4.4. Type Variables:**](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se7/html/jls-4.html#jls-4.4)

> Every type variable declared as a type parameter has a bound. If no
>   bound is declared for a type variable, Object is assumed. If a bound
>   is declared, it consists of either:
>
> ```
> - a single type variable T, or
>
> - a class or interface type T possibly followed by interface types `I1 & ... & In`.
> ```
>
> It is a compile-time error if any of the types `I1 ... In` is a **class**
>   type or type variable.

So, for an expression `<T extends C & I> void test(T t)`, `I` should be an interface.

Comment: `I` in the original question was `Cloneable`, which is an interface. The problem was in the `C`, which must be a class or interface (but not a type variable).

Comment: @yshavit, please, take a look at the start of my answer, where i quoted one of his question. He actually had two question. I pasted the question with `>` code by with `<` it was hiding the `<T1,T2 extends Cloneable & T1>` part in the post. :)

Comment: don't be, it is my fault that i could not paste it correctly :)