# Nesting generics into generics

Tags: java, generics

Lets say I have 2 interfaces which define some kind of container format holding a specific type of data.

```
public interface Content {
}

public interface Holder1<T extends Content> {
}

public interface Holder2<T extends Content> {
}
```

Now I want some converter which defines objects that can transform an object of type `Holder1` into an `Holder2`.

This converter should keep information about the kind of objects stored within the original object:

```
public interface ConverterPrototype1 {
   public <U extends Content> Holder2<U> convert(Holder1<U> source);
}
```

But I also want to be able to restrict the type of `Holder1` that some converter can work on:

```
interface ConverterPrototype2<U extends Content, V extends Holder1<U>> {
   public Holder2<U> convert(V source);
}
```

Is there a way to combine the semantics of these 2 interfaces into a single one? Something like

```
//INVALID CODE!
interface CombinedConvertor<V extends Holder1> {
   public <U extends Content> Holder2<U> convert(V<U> source);
}
```

I'm not sure if my title is suited for this problem, but I couldn't find a better description... Similar problems posted here always seemed to talk about different things.

**Edit:**
After stumbling upon [this link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/745756/java-generics-wildcarding-with-multiple-classes), I came up with following code. It is still invalid, but closer to actual java code.

```
//INVALID CODE!
interface CombinedConvertor<X extends Source<?>> {
    public <U extends Content, V extends X & Source<U>> Target<U> convert(V source);
}
```

Comment: I might just be missing something but ... you already guarantee that `Holder1` and `Holder2` can only hold something that extends `Content` in their definitions.

Comment: Correct, but I'd like to know the specific type that is returned when using the Convertor (for whatever possible implementation of `Content`), instead of simply working with the interface. I hope that makes sense :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After finding the format of code posted in my edit, I found many related items talking about this problem. It appears the java language simply does not support this case. I can recommend [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13101991/java-generics-make-generic-to-extends-2-interfaces) to learn more about the details of this limitation.

Answer (score 0):

It is possible to create a `CombinedConvertor` interface, as long as you define another generic type parameter to represent the single generic type parameter of `Holder1`, as you already have done to `ConverterProptotype2`.  This removes the generic type parameter from the `convert` method and adds it to the interface itself.

```
interface CombinedConvertor<U extends Content, V extends Holder1<U>> {
   public  Holder2<U> convert(V source);
}
```

Comment: I'm not really sure I understand, using `ConvertorPrototype2` I wouldn't be able to do the following, for example:
`Holder2<MyContent> holder2 = convertor.convert(new Holder1Impl<MyContent>())`. That is, I want to leave the generic type of the content out of the interface description.

Answer (score 0):

If I'm understanding what you're asking, and from your comment to the other answer ... you can infer both.

```
public interface Converter
{
    public <U extends Content, V extends Holder1<U>> Holder2<U> convert(V source);
}
```

Comment: This is pretty close, but it doesn't allow me to restrict the type of `Holder1` to be used as input parameter for the `Converter`. For example, I'd like to have a converter that works only on `Holder1SubInterface`.